# How to print the method name to NetBeans Debugger Console?

Tags: netbeans

<sub>This is a follow-up question to [@MatthewD's question 'How do I write to the Netbeans Debugger Console (in Java)?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361024/how-do-i-write-to-the-netbeans-debugger-console-in-java)</sub>

For a NetBeans breakpoint, it is possible to print line number, class name and thread name using `{lineNumber}`, `{className}` and `{threadName}` respectively. Is there also a simmilar expression for method name?

I have unsuccessfully tested `{method}` and `{methodName}`, and searched through [NetBeans JPDA API](http://bits.netbeans.org/6.9/javadoc/org-netbeans-api-debugger-jpda/%20NB%20JPDA%20API) and [NetBeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org), but found nothing. I'd rather write `{methodName}` in the breakpoint's properties than the name itself, that cannot be copy-pasted or used as template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{methodName}` works fine for me, on Netbeans 7.0.1.

The only reference I found about these keywords is [in a bug ticket](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=58800) :

The full list is :

```
{threadName}
{className}
{methodName}
{lineNumber}
{=EXPRESSION}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't really get it. After your post, I have tested it today again (NetBeans 7.2) and it works... Probably, lack of sleep!